# Codeigniter not closing MYSQL connections

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, connection

I have a REST API I created in Codeigniter/PHP with a MYSQL database. I have computers hitting it all day and night, doing very quick calls that run fast and return very small amounts of data. When I call "show full processlist", I don't see any active connections, but over time I keep maxing out the MYSQL connections. I'm pretty certain that my connections aren't getting closed somewhere. I thought Codeigniter handles all this. I can't figure out where or how this is occurring. I have persistent connections off, and I am closing the connection on the destruct method to be sure.

Can anyone provide some debugging techniques that would help me figure out what is causing all these connection to get opened and not closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're gettting problemns with the initial configurations from Codeigniter connection database.

At this page, you can see each value from config array: [Link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array()
);
```

This it's a basic array config database, try to set the variable of `pconnect` to FALSE, when it is turned on, the system doesn't close any connection and it stays open to news queries at any time.

If you set it to false like I said, your system will continue working perfectly, but the CodeIgniter will close and open the connection when he need's to use the database.

Here is the Helpful link to [CodeIgniter forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-68024-post-343764.html#pid343764)